# open /usr/local/share/xray/iran.dat: no such file or directory

Tags: server, vpn

I am Trying to setup a VPN Server With Xray i get this error open /usr/local/share/xray/iran.dat: no such file or directory but when i enter
ls -l /usr/local/share/xray/iran.dat the output is -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1763147 Jun 14 17:17 /usr/local/share/xray/iran.dat

tried chmod 777 * in /usr/local/share/xray foler

Answer (score 1):

You need to log into your panel, Then navigate to config in the sidebar, Finally reset to default in the bottom of the screen
After that ssh to your server and restart your x-ui to do so there is 2way:

1. Type "x-ui" then put the number of restart, it must be "11"
2. Type "x-ui restart"